# Delete the [wish], [harry-potter], and other tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

IMO, [wish](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wish) (**deleted**) and [harry-potter](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) (**deleted**) do not appear to serve any useful purpose and can be deleted. Other tags which appear ripe for deletion/synonymisation:

- [ic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ic)
- [ian](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ian)
- [tech-speak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tech-speak)
- [management-speak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management-speak)
- [genericized-trademarks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genericized-trademarks)
- [polisemy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polisemy)
- [productiveness](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/productiveness)

I'm not sure about these either:

- [untagged](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)
- [idiomaticity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomaticity) ([Suggested](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) as a synonym of [idioms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms))
- [acceptability](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acceptability)

---

**Edit:** I've added a **(deleted)** note to those tags which have been deleted. Users who can should visit the [suggested synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) page and vote on any pending suggestions.

Comment: [tag:untagged] is a system tag. If you see a post that has it, then the post's been migrated and the tags it had before don't exist here.

Comment: To be exact, [tag:untagged] is used by the system when a migrated question is not using any of the tag used from the site receiving the question. Only existing tags are kept, and when the question doesn't have any existing tag, [tag:untagged] is added since questions need at least a tag. Those questions are normally the ones migrated from moderators, as a migration is blocked when the question is not using tags used from the destination site.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, delete those tags! I just noticed the [wish](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wish) tag too! There are four instances of it, I believe. Consider also as candidates for deletion:

- [schwa](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schwa): There is only one question on the entire site with that tag.
- [word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word) and its synonym [words](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/words): It seems to be used primarily by one person (user account).
- [term](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/term) and [terms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terms): Neither have any associated questions.

Comment: There was consensus regarding [tag:word] in the past, see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/140/word-tag-useful The answer was 'delete'.

Comment: Just because there is only one question tagged [tag:schwa] does not mean there are not others were it would be merited.

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to cut the `schwa` tag; we could easily get by with the `pronunciation` and `vowels` tags. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @tchrist I don't have a strong opinion either way regarding the [tag:schwa] tag. If you believe that it should stay, I will defer to you. I would ask this though: If it is kept, then it should have a non-blank tag wiki. I could write one, but it is not my forte. (Schwa, that is. I can do tag wiki's in general ;o)

Comment: If we keep [tag:schwa] why not have a tag for every letter of the alphabet, plus one for each diacritical mark?

Comment: Don't! Schwa is my favourite word! For good reason too.

Answer (score 4):

I agree.

Synonyms will stop deleted tags being resurrected in the future.

Perhaps [management-speak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/management-speak) should be a synonym of [business-language](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business-language).

Perhaps [tech-speak](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tech-speak) should be a synonym of [computing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computing).

Perhaps [idiomaticity](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiomaticity) should be a synonym of [idioms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms).

Comment: [tag:tech-speak] would also fit into [tag:jargon].

Comment: Yes, I would like [tag:idiomaticity] made a synonym of [tag:idioms]. Idiomaticity is recent, with only two tagged questions, so now would be an appropriate time to put the synonym in place, I believe.

Comment: I found [IDIOMS AND IDIOMATICITY](http://infolanka.com/org/diary/30.html) which is a precis of an entire book on the subject. It says that there is a mild distinction between the two. For our purposes here, I still believe the tags should be synonyms.

Answer (score 4):

Questions with [genericized-trademarks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genericized-trademarks) should have been retagged with [trademarks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trademarks), rather than untagged. Unless [trademarks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trademarks) should be deleted, or [genericized-trademarks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/genericized-trademarks) were a mistagging in the first place. Please take more care next time!